# sql left join returns

Tags: sql, left-join, conditional-statements, records

I am trying to run a left join on 2 tables. I do not have a group by and the only where condition i have is on the second table. But, the returned rows are less than the first table. isn't the left join suppose to bring all the data from the first table? 
Here is my SQL:

```
select * 
  from tbl_a A left join tbl_b B
     ON
       A.Cnumber=B.Cnumber
       and A.CDNUmber=B.CDNumber
       and abs(A.duration - B.Duration)<2
       and substr(A.text,1,3)||substr(A.text,5,8)||substr(A.text,9,2)=substr(B.text,1,8)
where B.fixed = 'b580'
```

There are 140,000 records in table A but the result returned is less than 100,000 records. What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: my main issue here is to get the exact 140000 records in the result, some having the tbl_b records if the conditions match and some dont

Comment: actually i can not give samples but as for an example : consider matching 2 list in a school. one for the whole students created by the school. and another created by the respective ministry. the ministry list has more records. i want to find out which records in the ministry list is not in our list. none of the tables has a primary key and 4 columns together can make a record unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as you put a condition in the `WHERE` clause that references the right table and doesn't accommodate the `NULL`s that will be produced when the join is unsuccessful, you've transformed it (effectively) back into an `INNER JOIN`.

Try:

```
where B.fixed = 'b580' OR B.fixed IS NULL
```

Or add this condition to the `ON` clause for the `JOIN`.

Comment: I moved the condition from [where] to [ON]. the number of records went up to 280000. i think i may have multiple matches. am i right?

Comment: Yes, that sounds likely. If you're not seeing the results you *want*, could you update your question with some sample data and the results you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I tbl_c and inserted the joined reults in it and then i tried this code to remove the duplicates in the results: select count(*) from tbl_C  where rowid not in ( select min(rowid) from tbl_c group by Cnumber1 ,CDNUmber2 ,duration1,text1;   the result has went to 150000 records. why is it still more than the first table?

Comment: all the fields i have mentioned in the query are from the first table.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the where clause to the join:

```
select * 
  from tbl_a A left join tbl_b B
     ON
       A.Cnumber=B.Cnumber
       and A.CDNUmber=B.CDNumber
       and abs(A.duration - B.Duration)<2
       and substr(A.text,1,3)||substr(A.text,5,8)||substr(A.text,9,2)=substr(B.text,1,8)
  and B.fixed = 'b580'
```

If you use where statemen all records where b is not existing will not returned.

Comment: i now have extra records even by removing duplicates in the new list.?!?!

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Comment: actually i can not give samples but as for an example : consider matching 2 list in a school. one for the whole students created by the school. and another created by the respective ministry. the ministry list has more records. i want to find out which records in the ministry list is not in our list. none of the tables has a primary key and 4 columns together can make a record unique columns together can make a record unique.