# Sql Left join returns nothing

Tags: sql, left-join

I want to join table of **products** and table of **orders** in a way that all products are listed and price of all ordered product by current user are shown (However some of those prices are 0 because there is no order submitted for that product).

As the user confirms the list, An invoiceId is produced for all products in this list. So the invoiceId is null in this step yet (which is my question).

There are many products in first table but why the output is empty?

**Table products:**

> id   |   price

**Table orders:**

> id   |   ProductId    |    member   |   invoiceId

(I added `orders.member is null` regarding to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28039591/sql-left-join-returns) but no chance yet):

```
Select * from products left join orders 
on products.id=orders.productId 
where (orders.member='"&request.cookies("member")&"' or  orders.member is null) 
and orders.invoiceId is null
```

**Edit:**
My Guess: There are also orders of other members. Does they violate current **where condition**?

Comment: `where (orders.member='"&request.cookies("member")&"' or  orders.member is null) and order.invoiceId is null` has to be filtering out all of the rows, double check the condition.

Comment: I don't want to include orders of other members but I don't know how to update the conditions.

Comment: Try using OUTER JOIN, special for your use case

Comment: @Osy: he is already using an outer join

Comment: Post some example data that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Moving conditions on second table to **on** instead of **where** solved the problem. Who deleted his answer and why?

Comment: No really an outer join @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @osy: a `left join` **IS** an outer join

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name,  I read "left join" tag tooltip and you right, however in Oracle database there is a huge difference using LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN

Comment: @osy: no. there is absolutely **no** difference between `left join` and `left outer join`. None whatsoever. Not in Oracle. Nor in any other DBMS.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is on the second table.  Hence, it should go in the `on` clause:

```
Select *
from products p left join
     orders o
    on p.id = o.productId and
       o.member='"&request.cookies("member")&"'
where o.invoiceId is null;
```

Comment: Why you didn't move the last condition?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour . . . That would turn the outer join into an inner.  This seemed the most likely logic that you want.

Comment: moving condition to **ON** returns more rows!